# Drawing terms of sum in a plot tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

(don't know how to write mathematical expressions on this forum). I am trying to plot the following function

```
\begin{align*}
       f : [0,1] &\longrightarrow \RE, \\
              x  &\mapsto \begin{cases} x, &x \in \{ 0,1\}\\ s_k, &\text{for } x \in (s_{k - 1}, s_k] \end{cases}
   \end{align*}
```

In Tikz. Here is what i have so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, 
ymin=0, ymax=1, ytick={0,0.25,...,0.75}, ylabel=$f(x)$, 
xmin = 0,xmax=1, xtick={0,0.25,...,0.75}, xlabel=$x$,
legend pos=north west,legend style={draw=none}
]
\addplot[domain=0:0.5]{0.5};
\addplot[domain=0.5:0.75]{0.75};
\addplot[domain=0.75:0.875]{0.825};
%\addplot[domain=0:0.5]{0.5};
\end{axis}
```

Ideally, i would write it the following way in code:

```
var s = 0;

for i = 1, i <= 10, i++ {
    s' = s;
    s += 2^{-i};
    \addplot[domain=s':s]{s}
}
```

And this way i would get the desired Result. But i don't know how to convert that to Tikz...
Any help would be welcome!

Comment: You could create the function using pgfmath, but the discontinuities would be filled in by addplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your pseudo-coded loop in PGFPlots as well.

Instead of `\foreach` from PGF/TikZ you will need to use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` or `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` because PGFPlots doesn't immediatly process its plots.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, 
ymin=0, ymax=1, ytick={0,0.25,...,0.75}, ylabel=$f(x)$, 
xmin = 0,xmax=1, xtick={0,0.25,...,0.75}, xlabel=$x$,
legend pos=north west,legend style={draw=none}
]
\pgfmathsetmacro\domainEnd{0}                      % s = 0
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1, ..., 10}{
  \let\domainStart\domainEnd                       % s' = s
  \pgfmathsetmacro\domainEnd{\domainStart+2^(-\i)} % s += 2^{-i}
  \addplot[domain=\domainStart:\domainEnd] {\domainEnd};
}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An altenative without `pgfmath` code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
axis lines=center,
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1, 
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f(x)$,
xtick distance=0.25, ytick distance=0.25,
enlargelimits=0.1,
]
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}
\addplot[domain={1-2^(-\i+1)}:{1-2^-\i}]{1-2^(-\i)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with horizontal line steps]